# R: Identify (partial) matching cells

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a table with several thousand rows and hundreds of columns. Instead of filtering the table, I need to **identify the cells** that (partially) match several keywords.
All I could find so far is the function  WhichCells {SeuratObject} - alas I cannot get it to work.

For example

```
Column1 <- c("Temperature", "Water", "Sun", "tree fighter", "rainbow")
Column2 <- c(60.1, 106, 78.6, 21.5, 71)
Column3 <- c("Another cell", NA, "more content", NA, "Thanks!")
    
df <- data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3)
df

pattern <- c("temp", "content", 55, "heart", "thanks")
```

The desired result would look like

```
pattern   Column    Row
1    temp Column1   1
2 content Column3   3
3  thanks Column3   5
```

Note: rows could also be returned as rownames.

Please, could anyone give advice how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is part of the answer but you should do some adjustment to take into account upper/lower case :

```
pattern <- c("Temp", "content", 55, "heart", "Thanks")

detectpattern <- function(df, pattern){
    colindex <- which(apply(df, 1, str_detect, pattern = pattern))
    rowindex <- which(apply(df, 2, str_detect, pattern = pattern))
    return(c(pattern, colindex, rowindex))
}

for (pat in pattern){
    print(detectpattern(df = df, pattern = pat))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
df %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(., var = "Row") %>%
  melt(id.vars = "Row", value.name = "patterns", variable.name = "Column") %>% 
  mutate(check = ((sapply(pattern, function(x) {str_detect(patterns, regex(x, ignore_case = T)) %>% as.numeric} ))%>% rowSums(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  filter(check == 1) %>% select(-check)


  Row  Column     patterns
1   1 Column1  Temperature
2   3 Column3 more content
3   5 Column3      Thanks!
```